# How to go through the elements of a matrix, layer by layer

Tags: algorithm, matrix

It is difficult to explain what I want. Lets say I have a matrix of 0 and 1

000000
000000
001100
000000
000000

I want to start from a certain group of ones (this is given in the beginning, and then I want to go outwards.

000000,,,,,,,  000000
011110 OR 001100
010010,,,,,,,    010010
011110,,,,,,,    001100
000000,,,,,,,    000000

The difference is not important, as long as I will go through everything, outwards.

The reason I want to do this is, this matrix of 1 and 0 corresponds to a matrix of some 2D function, and I want to examine the points in that function going outwards. I want to

Comment: I would: 1. Make a first pass, setting every 0-cell that has a neighbouring 1-cell to 2.  2. Make a second pass, setting every 1-cell to 0 and every 2-cell to 1.  3. Goto 1.  It's unclear what you want to happen if the original group of 1-cells has a "hollow interior" (0-cells inside it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, basically what you want is to find a group of 1s inside a matrix and invert the group of 1s and all of it's surrounding. This is actually an image-processing problem, so my explanation will be accordingly. Sidenote: the term 'polygon' is here used for the group of 1s in the matrix. Some assumptions made: the polygon is always filled. The polygon doesn't contain any points that are directly at the outer bounds of the matrix (ex.: the point (0 , 2) is never part of the polygon). The solution can be easily found this way:

Step 1: search an arbitrary 1 that is part of the outer bound of the polygon represented by the 1s in the matrix. By starting from the upper left corner it's guaranteed that the returned coordinated will belong to a 1 that is either on the left side of the polygon, the upper-side or at a corner.

```
point searchArb1(int[][] matrix)
    list search
    search.add(point(0 , 0))

    while NOT search.isEmpty()
        point pt = search.remove(0)

        //the point wasn't the searched one
        if matrix[pt.x][pt.y] == 1
            return pt

        //continue search in 3 directions: down, right, and diagonally down/right
        point tmp = pt.down()
        if tmp.y < matrix.height
            search.add(tmp)

        tmp = pt.right()
        if tmp.x < matrix.width
            search.add(tmp)

        tmp = pt.diagonal_r_d()
        if tmp.x < matrix.width AND tmp.y < matrix.height
            search.add(tmp)

    return null
```

Step 2: now that the we have an arbitrary point in the outer bound of the polygon, we can simply proceed by searching the outer bound of the polygon. Due to the above mentioned assumptions, we only have to search for 1s in 3 directions (diagonals are always represented by 3 points forming a corner). This method will search the polygon bound clockwise.

```
int UP = 0
int RIGHT = 1
int DOWN = 2
int LEFT = 3

list searchOuterBound(int[][] matrix , point arbp)
    list result

    point pt = arbp
    point ptprev

    //at each point one direction can't be available (determined using the previous found 1
    int dir_unav = LEFT

    do
        result.add(pt)

        //generate all possible candidates for the next point in the polygon bounds
        map candidates

        for int i in [UP , LEFT]
            if i == dir_unav
                continue

            point try
            switch i
                case UP:
                    try = pt.up()
                    break
                case DOWN:
                    try = pt.down()
                    break
                case RIGHT:
                    try = pt.right()
                    break
                case LEFT:
                    try = pt.left()
                    break

            candidates.store(i , try)

        ptprev = pt

        for int i in [0 , 2]
            //the directions can be interpreted as cycle of length 4
            //always start search for the next 1 at the clockwise next direction
            //relatively to the direction we come from
            //eg.: dir_unav = LEFT -> start with UP
            int dir = (dir_unav + i + 1) % 4

            point try = candidates.get(dir)

            if matrix[pt.x][pt.y] == 1
                //found the first match
                pt = try
                //direction we come from is the exact opposite of dir
                dir_unav = (dir + 2) % 4
                break

        //no matching candidate was found
        if pt == ptprev
            return result
    while pt != arbp

    //algorithm has reached the starting point again
    return result
```

Step 3: Now we've got a representation of the polygon. Next step: Inverting the points around the polygon aswell. Due to the fact that the polygon itself will be filled with 0s later on, we can simply fill up the surrounding of every point in the polygon with 1s. Since there are two options for generating this part of the matrix-state, i'll split up into two solutions:
Step 3.1: Fill points that are diagonal neighbours of points of the polygon with 1s aswell

```
void fillNeighbours_Diagonal_Included(int[][] matrix , list polygon)
    for point p in polygon
        for int x in [-1 , 1]
            for int y in [-1 , 1]
                matrix[p.x + x][p.y + y] = 1
```

Step 3.1: Don't fill points that are diagonal neighbours of points of the polygon

```
void fillNeighbours_Diagonal_Excluded(int[][] matrix , list polygon)
    for point p in polygon
        matrix[p.x - 1][p.y] = 1
        matrix[p.x + 1][p.y] = 1
        matrix[p.x][p.y - 1] = 1
        matrix[p.x][p.y + 1] = 1
```

Step 4: Finally, last step: Invert all 1s in the polygon into 0s. Note: I'm too lazy to optimize this any further, so this part is implemented as brute-force.

```
void invertPolygon(int[][] matrix , list polybounds)
    //go through each line of the matrix
    for int i in [0 , matrix.height]
        sortedlist cut_x

        //search for all intersections of the line with the polygon
        for point p in polybounds
            if p.y == i
                cut_x.add(p.x)

        //remove ranges of points to only keep lines
        int at = 0
        while at < cut_x.size()
            if cut_x.get(at - 1) + 1 == cut_x.get(at) 
               AND cut_x.get(at) == cut_x.get(at + 1) - 1
                   cut_x.remove(at)
                   --at

        //set all points in the line that are part of the polygon to 0
        for int j in [0 , cut_x.size()[ step = 2
            for int x in [cut_x.get(j) , cut_x.get(j + 1)]
                matrix[x][i] = 0
```

I hope you understand the basic idea behind this. Sry for the long answer.